# how to use any statistical stemmer like YASS or GRAS in place of Porter stemmer in TERRIER Information Retreival system

Tags: java

Terrier IR system uses Porter Stemmer by default. How can we use statistical stemmers output in Terrier? i have generated the stem list using statistical stemmer and want to embed it in TERRIER IR.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class extending StemmerTermPipeline into the org.terrier.terms package.

For instance:

public class StatisticalStemmer extends StemmerTermPipeline {

```
public StatisticalStemmer(TermPipeline next) {
    super(next);
}

@Override
public String stem(String word) {
   // your method implementation
}
```

}

Afterwards, you need to recompile the core component and to substitute the terrier-4.0-core.jar file in the lib directory.

Lastly, you need to update the Term Pipeline in the property file:

termpipelines=Stopwords,StatisticalStemmer

In this way, Terrier will use you stemmer in place of the PorterStemmer.